# Why Javaw in Apache-Tomcat can only be stopped using taskkill /F

Tags: tomcat, javaw

I am very new to this so please excuse me if what I am asking is obvious.

From what I have read and observed on Windows java and javaw are identical except javaw runs without a console. Why is it then that javaw can only be terminated using taskkill /F ?

I discovered this while looking for a way to shut down Apache Tomcat server (v 6.0.36) via command prompt. The shutdown script works for `java.exe` but not `javaw.exe`. 
Furthermore I would like to know if there is a workaround for `javaw.exe` to close gracefully. I came across `SendSignal.exe` http://www.latenighthacking.com/projects/2003/sendsignal/ and tried it with no luck.

Thanks